# Timer (HH:MM:SS) with javascript for online task

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I want to implement a simple Timer (HH:MM:SS) for calculating the time spend by user doing online task, the timer should start when the page is loaded and stop when the user press the button to submit a result of his task.
HH: hours
MM: minutes
SS: seconds

Comment: And your attempt looks like…?

Comment: Wondering what your code looks like...

Comment: I think that the goal of this kind of website is to help people who doesn't know the answer for their concern. if I know how to implement a Timer in JS, you think that I come here asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for maintaining time :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateClock(); 
  setInterval('updateClock()', 250 );
});


function updateClock ( )
{
  //Set Current Time Variables
  var currentTime = new Date ( );
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var currentMiliSeconds = currentTime.getMilliseconds();
  var rounded = currentSeconds + (currentMiliSeconds / maxmilisecs);

  //Get Color Percentages based off time.
  //Percentage of 255 for Color
  //Percentage of 100 for Position
  rednum = (Math.round(255 * ((currentHours) / maxnumhours)));   
  rednum100 = (Math.round(100 * ((currentHours) / maxnumhours)));
  greennum = (Math.round(255 * ((currentMinutes) / maxnummins)));
  greennum100 = (Math.round(100 * ((currentMinutes) / maxnummins)));
  bluenum = (Math.round(255 * ((rounded) / maxnumsecs)));
  bluenum100 = (Math.round(100 * ((rounded) / maxnumsecs)));

  //convert to HEX
  redhex = hexifyWithZeroLead(rednum);
  greenhex = hexifyWithZeroLead(greennum);
  bluehex = hexifyWithZeroLead(bluenum);

  //Create the Hex Strings
  var hex = "#" + redhex + greenhex + bluehex;      //Total HEX Value
  var fullredhex = "#"+redhex+"0000";               //RED Only Hex
  var fullgreenhex = "#00"+greenhex+"00";           //GREEN Only Hex
  var fullbluehex = "#0000"+bluehex;                //BLUE Only Hex

  //Text to indvidual color sliders
  jQuery("#red_display").html(redhex);
  jQuery("#green_display").html(greenhex);
  jQuery("#blue_display").html(bluehex);

  //Position and animate color sliders
  leftpos = (rednum100 * 0.01 * 575) + 25;
  jQuery('#red_display').animate({left: leftpos}, 200);
  jQuery('#red_display').css('background-color',fullredhex);

  leftpos = (greennum100 * 0.01 * 575) + 25;
  jQuery('#green_display').animate({left: leftpos}, 200);
  jQuery('#green_display').css('background-color',fullgreenhex);

  leftpos = (bluenum100 * 0.01 * 575) + 25;
  jQuery('#blue_display').animate({left: leftpos}, 200);
  jQuery('#blue_display').css('background-color',fullbluehex);


  //zerolead the time for display
  currentHours = ( currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentHours;
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

  //append the values
  jQuery("#clock").html("<span id='hours'>"+ currentHours + "</span>:<span id='minutes'>" + currentMinutes + "</span>:<span id='seconds'>" + currentSeconds + '</span>');
  jQuery("#hex").html(hex);

  //change the background of the page to current HEX color
  //jQuery('.skin-blue .logo').css('background-color',hex);
  //jQuery('.skin-blue .navbar').css('background-color',hex);
  //jQuery('.skin-blue .sidebar a').css('color',hex);
}
```

Here is your div element

```
<div id="clock" style="color: white;width"><span id="hours"></span>:<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the whole code out for you as you haven't shown any of your own work but I will set you on your way.

You can create an date object `var firstDate = new Date;` on page load. Create a  function that creates another date object and get the difference between them. This gives the time in milliseconds. This can be converted into seconds, minutes and hours using mod and Math.floor(). You can then print this to the page using `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`. Then use `window.setTimeout("yourTimerFunction()",1000);` which re-calls your function every second.